# How can i print add value in input tag?

Tags: javascript

```
for( let i =0; i<productChcbx.length; i++) {
  productChcbx[i].addEventListener("click",()=> {
    let cnt = 0;
    for(let j =0; j<productChcbx.length; j++) {
      if(productChcbx[j].checked) {
        cnt++;
        if(cnt == 1) {
          addProduct.style.display = "flex";
          productAmount.innerHTML = "70,000원";
        } else if (cnt > 1) {
          sum=70000 + 60000 * (cnt-1);
          productAmount.innerHTML = number_format(sum) + "원";
        } 
      } else if (!productChcbx[j].checked) {
        if(cnt == 0) {
          addProduct.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  })
}

resultSum.value = localAmount + productAmount;
```

variable `localAmount` and `productAmount` is Price value
and I want to sum these two variables as `resultSum.value` but can't add two variable I don't know how to add those.

I mean Print This code ----> [object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]

my english not good so im sorry but my this problem bring me here
because ran into a problem three times..
Please give me inspiration...already thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.. The picture didn't come up!
Print this code-> [object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]

Comment: Generally images are not as useful as text.  Please include your HTML, not an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to perform math on HTML elements, not on numbers.

The code doesn't define either of these variables, but this line certainly implies that at least one of them is an element:

```
productAmount.innerHTML = "70,000원";
```

And the output demonstrates this as well:

```
[object HTMLSpanElement][object HTMLSpanElement]
```

To perform math, you want to use *numbers*.  For example, where you do this:

```
productAmount.innerHTML = "70,000원";
```

You might also store a numeric value:

```
productAmount.innerHTML = "70,000원";
productAmountValue = 70000;
```

(As a further exercise, you can investigate how to specify the numeric value once and then *format* that value as a string for the HTML element.)

Do the same for `localAmount`, wherever/whatever that is.  Then you can add the value from those numbers:

```
resultSum.value = localAmountValue + productAmountValue;
```

(This could be another opportunity for investigate formatting a number for output.)

Comment: Thank you so much! David
you are my god... have a nice day